# Form a number using some numbers and mathematical operations

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

Using 2,3,4,5,6,7 and basic mathematical operations form the number 1088.

Every digit must be used exactly once (neither zero nor greater than one times).  Concatenation of digits (such as 53) is not allowed. Each operator can be used multiple times or not at all in any combination. **This removes duplicates and creates it as having a unique solution**.

**Note:**

> Allowed Operations: $+,-,/,*, {}^{\displaystyle\large\hat{}} ,!,\sqrt{}$

Comment: Must we use all provided numbers or can we use only a subset of them? Do you allow repeats? Can we combine numbers to form multi-digit numbers (e.g. 23, 57 etc)? Also, is `^` exponentiation or XOR?

Comment: @ace Every digit exactly once.

Comment: ADG, you should explicitly state (edit it in) that parentheses are allowed if they are allowed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Update: This 4-operator answer is now disallowed by OP after rule change. The 6-operator one still works though.

An answer that uses 4 operators only (assuming concatenation to form multi-digit numbers is allowed):

$$ 523 \times \sqrt4 + 6 \times 7 = 1088 $$

---

Assuming we can use parentheses and they don't count as operators, then we have 6 operators with

$$ 7^3 + 6! + 5 ^ {(4-2)} = 1088 $$

If we can't use parentheses, then

$$ 7\;3\;{}^\wedge\;6\;!\;+\;5\;4\;2\;-\;{}^\wedge\;+ $$

which is the same thing in reverse Polish notation.

The above assumes that the `^` operator is for exponentiation, not XOR.

Comment: You can remove the parentheses in any case since $5^{4-2}$ is unambiguous.

Comment: @Lawrence I know, but the OP mentioned the `^` operator, not exponentiation. If we are to use the `^` operator, we would need to write `5^(4-2)` with parentheses needed. I'm not sure how the OP wants his answers.

Comment: I see - good call then :) .

Comment: From OP: "No concatenation" Your solutions using 523 and 73/542 are invalid.

Comment: @EngineerToast The OP stated that rule *after* my submission. (I asked him in the [comments](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/14708/form-a-number-using-some-numbers-and-mathematical-operations/14713?noredirect=1#comment45110_14708) but he did not reply.) Also, the last entry is the same as the second but written in [reverse Polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation).

Comment: @EngineerToast Actuially it has a unique solution, that I want, but It was my mistake that I forgot some rules. Sorry Everyone.

Comment: @ADG How is my other solution wrong then? The accepted answer has parentheses as well.

Comment: It's not wrong. Sorry I didn't noticed. Now we have two correct answer (maybe there's many others). I think I need to take help/discussion what to do in such cases. :( Sorry

Comment: I am honestly impressed. I very much wish I could grasp math like this. Whenever puzzles like this come up my self esteem takes a giant hit

Comment: @zfrisch Don't worry... To solve these questions you only need a rough idea of the size of numbers (e.g. in this case for my first (now invalid) solution I recognized $1088\approx1000=500\times2$), then made adjustments little by little, randomly trying on a calculator until I got 1088. For the second answer I knew I need to get to a big number using as few digits as possible, so I tried $7^3+6!$ and $6^4$ and started trying from there. Again, the rest is just calculator work (and a lot of free time, and perhaps some luck).

Answer (score 5):

The Answer is

> 7!/5 + 6!/(2+3+4)

Answer (score 3):

**Here is another possible solution:**

$(5!/4 \ + \ 3)^2 \ -  \ 7 \ + \ 6 \ = \ 1088$

Answer (score 1):

One other possible answer:
$$6! \times \frac{3}{2} + 5 + 7 - 4 = 1088$$

Answer (score -3):

Simple answer:

$1088=2^{(2*5)}+64$

If we must use every digit once....

$1088=2^{(3+7)}+64$

Comment: Every digit exactly once.

Comment: @ADG Minor edit; solved it!

Comment: sorry that I am not able to tell you the problem exactly. I use every digit once and exactly once, you have no 5. No concatenation like 64. But you can use an operator many times.